# Segmentation fault on malloc c

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I've been reading other posts trying to figure this out but haven't been able to.
I'm calling a function that requires a pointer to a pointer for the result, like this:

```
int plaintext_len = 0;
unsigned char *plaintext = NULL;
plaintext_len = token_decrypt( login_token, &plaintext );
```

and `token_decrypt` does the decryption fine, like this:
The following `gcm_decrypt` function returns the plaintext length and stored the plaintext text in `my_plaintext`.

```
int token_decrypt( const char *jwt_token, unsigned char **plaintext ) {
        int ret = 0;
        unsigned char my_plaintext[1024];
        ...
        ret = gcm_decrypt( 
            (unsigned char*)token_decoded.c_str(),
            ciphertext_len, 
            (unsigned char*)aad.c_str(), 
            aad_len, 
            (unsigned char*)tag.c_str(),
            (unsigned char*)decoded_key.c_str(), 
            (unsigned char*)iv.c_str(), 
            iv_len, 
            my_plaintext 
        );
        printf("my_plaintext: '%s'\n", my_plaintext ); <---- prints correctly the result.
        *plaintext = (unsigned char *)malloc( sizeof(char) * ret );
        memcpy( *plaintext, my_plaintext, ret );
        printf("token plaintext: '%s'\n", plaintext );
        return ret;
```

But executing segfaults on

```
*plaintext = (unsigned char *)malloc( sizeof(char) * ret );
```

Comment: Do you define `char plaintext[20] = "foobar";` or `char *plaintext = "foobar";` before `plaintext_len = token_decrypt( login_token, &plaintext );`?

Comment: I've found that a seg fault on calling `malloc()` or `free()` is often a result of a memory error elsewhere that has corrupted the heap.

Comment: So what is the value of `ret` which you have otherwise not used? You should print that along with the string.

Comment: Among other things, you don't provide the declaration of `plaintext` nor is it possible to know if `ret` is assigned correctly, this is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: most likely you have to malloc 1 byte more space for the string `malloc(sizeof(char)*(ret+1))` in order to copy it and to print. You probably corrupted malloc struct before. Run valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do the allocation before calling the function:

```
plaintext = (unsigned char *)malloc( sizeof(char)*ret );
```

Answer (score 0):

You must allocate one extra byte for the null terminator and you must pass `*plaintext` to `printf()`, not `plaintext`.

```
        *plaintext = (unsigned char *)malloc( sizeof(char) * (ret + 1) );
        if (*plaintext) {
            memcpy( *plaintext, my_plaintext, ret );
            (*plaintext)[ret] = '\0';
            printf("token plaintext: '%s'\n", (char *)(*plaintext) );
            return ret;
        } else {
            /* emory allocation error */
            return -1;
        }
```

If you are targeting POSIX systems, you should use `strndup()` which is less error prone than allocating the memory yourself:

```
        *plaintext = (unsigned char *)strndup((char *)my_plaintext, ret);
        if (*plaintext) {
            printf("token plaintext: '%s'\n", (char *)(*plaintext) );
            return ret;
        } else {
            /* memory allocation error */
            return -1;
        }
```